# How do I describe jobs dynamically in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a number of jobs for different platforms I'd like to run in parallel. I'd like to build a different set of platforms for different situations (i.e. full build, smoke, pull request, etc.). How can I make a list of jobs dynamic based on variables?

For example, if this is one of the "hard-coded" implementations:

```
jobs:

- job: Platform1
  pool: Pool1
  steps:
      - template: minimal_template.yml
        parameters:
          BuildTarget: Platform1

- job: Platform2
  pool: Pool1
  steps:
      - template: minimal_template.yml
        parameters:
          BuildTarget: Platform2
        
- job: Platform3
  pool: Pool2
  steps:
      - template: minimal_template.yml
        parameters:
          BuildTarget: Platform3
```

How could I instead extract out a collection of variable sets, i.e.

```
[[Platform1, Pool1], [Platform2, Pool1], [Platform3, Pool2]]
```

And execute that on a pipeline like:

```
jobs:

??(Foreach platform in platforms)??

- job: $(platform[0])
  pool: $(platform[1])
  steps:
      - template: minimal_template.yml
        parameters:
          BuildTarget: $(platform[0])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define it in the `parameters` and loop it:

```
parameters:
  - name: Platforms
    type: object
    default:
      - name: 'Platform1'
        pool: 'Platform1Pool'
      - name: 'Platform2'
        pool: 'Platform2Pool'
jobs:
- ${{ each platform in parameters.Platforms}}:        
  - job: ${{ platform.name }}
     pool: ${{ platform.pool }}
     steps:
         - template: minimal_template.yml
```

Comment: The _Each_ keyword is described in the docs here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#each-keyword

Comment: This is what I ended up using, however I put `jobs:` above the `each platform`. Thanks!

Comment: @House you're right! I fixed my syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You may alos use 'jobList' type for template parameters:

```
parameters:
- name: 'testsJobsList'
  type: jobList
  default: []

jobs:
- ${{ each job in parameters.testsJobsList }}: # Each job
  - ${{ each pair in job }}:          # Insert all properties other than "steps"
      ${{ if ne(pair.key, 'steps') }}:
        ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}
    steps:                            # Wrap the steps
    - ${{ job.steps }}                # Users steps
```

And then:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

jobs:
- template: deployment-template.yml
  parameters:
    testsJobsList: 
      - job: Platform1
        pool: Platform1Pool
        steps:
        - template: minimal_template.yml
      - job: Platform2
        pool: Platform2Pool
        steps:
        - template: minimal_template.yml
```

Answer (score 0):

You’re looking for conditions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Stages, jobs, and steps can all have a condition defined.

For example, running a job if a variable is set to true:

```
condition: eq(variables['System.debug'], 'true')
```